# how to obtain spring context reference in jpbm 4.2 EventListener?

Tags: spring, jbpm

How to obtain spring context from within EventListener instance which gets notified following this transition of process:

```
<transition g="-36,11" name="A" to="B">
   <event-listener class="com.test.handlers.MyRequestHandler">
   </event-listener>
</transition>
```

I want to be able to do something like the following in my

```
@Override
public void notify(EventListenerExecution execution) throws Exception {
..
MyOtherSpringBean sender = (MyOtherSpringBean )applicationContext.get("MyOtherSpringBean ");
```

Thanks in advance,

Denis

Answer (score 2):

You can have your `EventListener` be part of the spring context, and hence you can inject other beans into it (using `@Autowired private MyOtherSpringBean bean`)

See [this thread](http://community.jboss.org/thread/150105), and [this issue](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-2529)